# Update state in useState with object as input in function component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, jsx

Function component is used here

```
export default function Account() {
```

defining const with inputs as objects

```
const [state, setState] = useState({
  profile: true,
  orders: false,
  returns: false,
  coupon: false,
  referrals: false,
  rewards: false,
  redeem: false,
  address: false,
});
```

function to update state. I want to update state with setting all values in object to false and update specified key that is passes by `onClick`

```
function activeHandler(key) {
  setState((prevState) => {
    Object.keys(prevState).forEach((key) => {
      if (key == res) {
        prevState[key] = true;
      } else {
        prevState[key] = false;
      }
    });
    console.log(state);
    return prevState;
  });
}
```

JSX element, here `onClick` is used to pass key to function which is used to update state

```
return (
  <>
    <li
      className={
        state.profile
          ? "py-3 px-3 border-bottom active"
          : "py-3 px-3 border-bottom"
      }
      onClick={() => activeHandler("profile")}
    >
      Profile
    </li>
    <li
      className={
        state.orders
          ? "py-3 px-3 border-bottom active"
          : "py-3 px-3 border-bottom"
      }
      onClick={() => activeHandler("orders")}
    >
      Orders
    </li>
  </>
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't say there is any issue or ask for help with anything, but it's clear your `activeHandler` callback function is simply mutating state so I'll assume that's the issue you are asking for help with. The returned `state` necessarily needs to be a new object reference. Shallow copy any state and nested state that is being updated.

Example:

```
function activeHandler(key) {
  setState((prevState) => ({
    ...prevState,           // <-- shallow copy previous state
    [key]: !prevState[key], // <-- toggle value by key
  }));
}
```

## Update

> I want to set all prevState to false first and then update the state
> where I want specified key to be true

In this case I'd suggest creating a "default" object with all properties set false to be used as a "template" object, shallow copied *then* specific property overridden.

Example:

```
const defaultState = {
  profile: false,
  orders: false,
  returns: false,
  coupon: false,
  referrals: false,
  rewards: false,
  redeem: false,
  address: false,
};
```

...

```
function activeHandler(key) {
  setState({
    ...defaultState, // <-- shallow copy default state value
    [key]: true,     // <-- override value by key
  }));
}
```

### Suggestion

Since it seems you want only one "active" property at-a-time I'd suggest storing only the active key and checking that during the render.

Example:

```
const [active, setActive] = useState();

...

return (
  <>
    <li
      className={
        [
          "py-3 px-3 border-bottom",
          active === 'profile' ? 'active' : null
        ]
          .filter(Boolean)
          .join(" ")
      }
      onClick={() => setActive("profile")}
    >
      Profile
    </li>
    <li
      className={
        [
          "py-3 px-3 border-bottom",
          active === 'orders' ? 'active' : null
        ]
          .filter(Boolean)
          .join(" ")
      }
      onClick={() => setActive("orders")}
    >
      Orders
    </li>
  </>
);
```

Comment: i want to set all prevState to false first and then update the state where i want specified key to be true

Comment: @PonnuSudesh I see. I've updated my answer with an implementation and a suggestion, please do check them out when you can.